# how do you unset Signal.trap?

Tags: ruby

I have a loop that I want to stop on interrupt, but once I do this, the original behavior is lost..  How can I temporarily change the behavior of interrupt but then set it back so it can do what it normally does?

```
stop = false
trap = Signal.trap('INT') { stop = true } # returns "DEFAULT"
loop do
  break if stop
end
Signal.trap('INT') { trap } # <-- does not work
```

I know I can do:

```
Signal.trap('INT') do
  stop = true
  exit
end
```

But I would rather just let it do it's default behavior... How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it, but instead of wrapping the previous handler/value in a block, you have to pass it as a [positional argument](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Positional+Arguments):

```
stop = false
trap = Signal.trap('INT') { stop = true }
loop do
  break if stop
end
Signal.trap('INT', trap) # <- this way
```

This also works if the previous handler is a proc, i.e. procs can be given as both, block arguments (via `&`) or positional arguments:

```
handler = proc { stop = true }

Signal.trap('INT', handler)
# is treated as:
Signal.trap('INT', &handler)
# which is equivalent to:
Signal.trap('INT') { stop = true }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just explicitly set it to "DEFAULT" behavior, examples to demonstrate:

```rb
stop = false
Signal.trap("INT") { stop = true }
loop do
  break if stop
end

loop do
  # have to ctrl-\ to exit
  p "stuck forever"
  sleep 1
end
```

```rb
stop = false
Signal.trap("INT") { stop = true }
loop do
  break if stop
end

Signal.trap("INT", "DEFAULT")
loop do
  # ctrl-c now works
  p "not stuck forever"
  sleep 1
end
```

*https://ruby-doc.org/3.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-trap*